# angular/rxjs observable Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isStopped' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

```js
//example 1
const xd = new Observable(({ next }) => {
  next("3");
});

xd.subscribe(msg => console.log(msg));

//example 2
    const obs$ = new Observable();

    obs$.subscribe(mg => console.log(mg));

//example 3
 private socket: SocketIOClient.Socket;
  constructor(private url: string) {
    this.socket = io(this.url);
  }

  listen() {
    return new Observable(({ next }) => {
      this.socket.on("message", next)
    })
  }
```

They are all giving me the same error, what might have gone wrong ?

(Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isStopped' of undefined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like this,

```
const xd = new Observable((observer) => {
  // observable execution
  observer.next("3");
});

xd.subscribe(msg =>{
   console.log(msg)
},
(error)=>{
  console.error(error);
}
);
```

Comment: I think there is some issue in  creating Observable instance in this way. Can you try like in the answer. mean to say instead of {next}=>  use here (observer)=>{ observer.next("3")};

Comment: If the answer provided has worked then mark them accepted and this will help new people who are facing the same problems to find answers. cheers !!

Comment: Did it, I just couldn't realize how to do it from the phone

ps: You should update your answer to say that destructuring doesn't work in this case, to make it clearer at first sight